# Build a N-ary tree (recursively ?) in C

Tags: c, recursion

I have to build a tree that, starting from a string it keeps creating new nodes according to some transformation rules.

For example:

Given a string `aab`
And the following two transformation rules:

```
ab --> bba
b --> ba
```

The following tree would need to be built:

[image: Tree]

Notice that the build is done in a breadth mode. At each step I apply all transformation rules for each substring of the current node and that will be the children.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Representing the n_ary tree
typedef struct {
    char *value;
    struct t_children_list *children;
} tree;

typedef struct t_children_list {
    tree *child;
    struct t_children_list *next;
} children_list;

void initializeNode(tree **node, char *input)
{
  if((*node = malloc(sizeof(tree))) == NULL) { abort(); }
  (*node)->value = input;
  (*node)->children = NULL;
}

void createChildrenList(children_list **children, tree *transformation)
{
    if((*children = malloc(sizeof(children_list))) == NULL) { abort(); }
    (*children)->child = transformation;
    (*children)->next = NULL;
}

//Given a node, and a needle with a replacement. It will add the childrens to that node. 
void addTransformationsToNode(tree **origin, char *needle, char *replacement)
{
    char *str = (*origin)->value;
    for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
       //Logic to find the value of str_... Not relevant
             tree *transformation = NULL;
            initializeNode(&transformation, str_);
            //Add node to origin children list
            // If node doesn't have children yet, create a new list
            // Otherwise, add to end of children list
            children_list *children = NULL;
            createChildrenList(&children, transformation);
            if ((*origin)->children == NULL) {
                (*origin)->children = children;
            } else {
                children_list *current = (*origin)->children;
                while (current->next != NULL) {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                current->next = children;
            }
        }
    }

  }

void main()
{
  // Create the tree
  char *input = "aab";
  char *target = "bababab";
  tree *my_tree = NULL;
  initializeNode(&my_tree, input);

  addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree, "ab", "bba");
  addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree, "b", "ba");

}
```

This works correctly for the first level. But I am looking for a way where I could do the same for each node and children of that node. So, I start at origin, find all the transformations and then for reach transformations do the same. I fail to see how I could do this recursively...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a tree grow horizontally applying modifications to current node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048037/make-a-tree-grow-horizontally-applying-modifications-to-current-node)

Answer (score 1):

For "breadth-first", you might want to look at the universal binary tree (which can be constructed for any tree), where each node links to *first-child* and *next-sibling*. You could build the binary tree (breath-first) and then convert to n-ary.

Building one generation from a single string, you put the results in a list of nodes, linked by *next-sibling*. The next generation is to build one generation from each node in the list.

Iteratively or recursively, you use the repetition to coordinate a sequence of calls which apply to one node.

```
addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree, "ab", "bba");

addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree->children->child, "ab", "bba");
addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree->children->next->child, "ab", "bba");
addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree->children->next->next->child, "ab", "bba");

addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree->children->child->children->child, "ab", "bba");
addTransformationsToNode(&my_tree->children->child->children->next->child, "ab", "bba");
```

So for the *body*, you're following *next* pointers and calling `addTransformationsToNode` for each child (I'd do this in a loop). Then, you can recurse and do the same for the children of each child.

You'll need an extra parameter to control the depth of the recursion: some way to end the tree-construction.

---

I tried writing the function and got all confused. I think your `children_list` structure is unnecessarily complicated. I'd start with something much simpler.

```
typedef struct tree {
    char *val;
    struct tree *first_child;
    struct tree *next_sibling;
} tree;

tree *newnode(char *val){
    tree *node;
    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node) {
        node->val = val;
        node->first_child = NULL;
        node->next_sibling = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void printtree(tree *node) {
    if (node) {
        if (node->val)
            printf("%s, ", node->val);
        printtree(node->next_sibling);
        puts("");
        printtree(node->first_child);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually how I have it. However I fail to see how to build the tree recursively...

Comment: Hm. Yeah. I find it much easier to think about iteratively. I'll give it more thought and update when I've got more.

Comment: luser droog: Iterativally would work too, but how would I do it for each children of each node?

Comment: luser droog thanks for the edition. I see this when it's done statically, but what I fail to see is to do it dinamically. I mean, how would the recursion/iteration look like?

Comment: Uhm..I had the children_list because I considered that a node in the tree had multiple children, therefore a list of children is appropriate...

Comment: But that means you can't find the sibling from a node because the node doesn't know which list it's in. This is the same, but better, because you can traverse it different ways with just one structure. You still have lists of children, but it's child, child->next, child->next->next, child->next->next->next. It's "flatter".

Comment: Another idea. See [Tree stored in an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays) for a structure that's implicitly in breadth-first order. And [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Encoding_general_trees_as_binary_trees) is the structure I'm talking about above.